# Randomly landing on every member of a set while the set is growing: Does it help to play before all items are added?

Tags: probability, statistics

This question has come up with me in two different Final Fantasy games, where you want or need to collect every memory or skill through random selection where not all memories/skills are available until late in the (main) game (not in the random selection "game"). Collecting a memory/skill does not remove it from the set (you can randomly land on it again)

My question is: In terms of getting every entity in the set, does it help (in terms of the expected number of plays to pick every entity) to play this sub-game before all entities have been added to the set (assuming even probability distribution over all entities)?

If what I am asking doesn't make sense to you, please ask let me know in a comment and I will try to clarify the question.

Comment: Are you interested in the expected total number of plays, or the expected number of plays after the last item has become available?  I suspect the answers are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

A "draw" is wasted if you get something that you already have. The probability of picking something you already have is C/A, where C is the number of unique items you've collected, and A is the number of available items. For any number of collected items, you'll have a better chance of getting a new one if the number of available items is higher - you'd prefer the the chance to be C/(A+U), where U now is the number of "unavailable" items. By playing the game before all items are available, you're just increasing your likelihood of wasting draws by getting items you already have. The size of the set of "items you already have" is fixed, and you have a larger chance of being successful the larger the set of "items you still need" is. It's not beneficial to play the game before all items are available, as these represent cases where you have a 0% probability of getting certain items that are needed. Intuitively, it doesn't help to collect everything by playing rounds where it impossible to collect some things.